# Checking embedding type of a font

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

In my application i'm tryng to list in a combobox fonts intalled on Windows that are TrueType and have the embedding permission **EMBED_EDITABLE** so i can embed them later in a PDF.

First i list all fonts with

```
EnumFontFamiliesEx(dc, &lf, (FONTENUMPROC)EnumFontProc, lparam, 0);
```

and inside my CALLBACK function i check:

```
BOOL CALLBACK WFonteCombo::EnumFontProc(LPLOGFONT lplf, 
                                        LPTEXTMETRIC lptm, 
                                        DWORD dwType, 
                                        LPARAM lpData)
{
    if (dwType == TRUETYPE_FONTTYPE)
    {
        HDC hDC = ::CreateDC(_T("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
        _ASSERTE(hDC);

        ::SelectObject(hDC, lplf);

        ULONG privstatus = 0;
        LONG ttStatus;

        ttStatus = ::TTGetEmbeddingType(hDC, &privstatus);

        if (ttStatus == E_NONE)
        {
            if (privstatus == EMBED_EDITABLE)
            {
                //  Do Something.
            }
        }

        ::DeleteDC(hDC);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**TTGetEmbeddingType** is returning **E_NOTATRUETYPEFONT** but i know the font is TrueType because of my condition

```
if (dwType == TRUETYPE_FONTTYPE)
```

and because the first font returned is this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/marlett) (a TrueType Font).

Any ideas in what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're leaking the font that was originally in that DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs in the same problem.

My SelectObject was wrong, i can't select a **LPLOGFONT** first i must create a font with CreateFontIndirect and then select the **HFONT**.

```
HFONT hfont = ::CreateFontIndirect(lplf);
HGDIOBJ hOldFnt = ::SelectObject(hDC, hfont);
```

The error was a little misleading because it wasn't just not a TrueType font it wasn't any type of font.

Comment: Your [SelectObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx) call was wrong for a more mundane reason: It never evaluated the return value, which does indicate success and failure. Essentially, you weren't checking for errors.